# Generating points and discarding the first few points with Python

Tags: python

I have defined an array that contains 1000 points, to illustrate, something like this:

```
x = np.zeros([1000, 2])
for i in range(1001):
   x =  'int + [i , i] / 2'
```

How do I plot the points with plt.scatter()? I have tried with just inserting x, but it doent work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you're new to python, right now you are defining `x` to be (the exact same) string a 1000 times

Comment: How to scatter plot with matplotlib.pyplot: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.zeros([1000, 2])
for i in range(len(x)):
   x[i] =  [i/2 , i/2]

plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1])
plt.show()
```

If anything isn't clear, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thank you! I stumbled upon another mistake. It seems like I did not iterate through all 1000 points to store them. My code is for that part is:  x_i = (x_start + corners[np.random.randint(3)]) / 2' where corners is also a vector. How do i iterate through is, because it doesnt work with x[i]?

Comment: so mye question is how do I iterate through a 2D array?

Comment: What do you mean with x_start? Iterating through a 2D array can be done using another for-loop in this loop. Or something like: ‘for i,j in x’